# MSP430 - IDA Pro Free Binary Dump

Tags: ida, disassemblers, risc

I have a assembly dump from a MSP430 binary in a normal ascii text file as below:

```
46f4 <strcpy>
46f4:  0d4f           mov   r15, r13
46f6:  023c           jmp   #0x46fc <strcpy+0x8>
46f8:  1e53           inc   r14
46fa:  1d53           inc   r13
46fc:  6c4e           mov.b @r14, r12
46fe:  cd4c 0000      mov.b r12, 0x0(r13)
4702:  4c93           tst.b r12
4704:  f923           jnz   #0x46f8 <strcpy+0x4>
4706:  3041           ret
4708 <_unexpected_>
4708:  0013           reti  pc
```

Using Ida Pro Free, how can I "upload" a binary dump of this format so I can use IDA's flow graphs, visual aids, etc. I realized it's already dissasembled but I still want to use the features IDA Pro free offers.

Comment: you mean you want to extract the 0d4f023cxxxx convert them to binary and load a binary file you may need to sed grep and awk and strtoul the result yourself no disassembler I know of can parse and load a text file

Comment: When you open IDA Pro, there is an option to load various types of files (Windows, Unix, PE, ELF, etc.) There is also a tab for Embedded (.hex intel/MOS hexadecimal file, .p MAS Macro Assembler code File). It appears as though you could include an assembler dump, or at least make one based on what I already have. It would be nice to keep the addresses the same however, those listed on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

IDA Free does not support MSP430 (only x86) and neither can it load plain binary files. You need the full version of IDA (Starter or Pro) to do either.

Comment: does that mean the pro version can load a text file as posted  or does it need to be in the mspxxx format  ( i mean 0x0d as liefeed etc etc)

Comment: not "as posted", but it can load hex dumps or raw binaries